# Diagram of SQL Database Showing Table Names and Foreign Key Links

Tags: sql-server, ssms, diagram

I am working on my database using SSMS. My database is fairly large with several hundred tables. I would like to create a entity resource diagram with only the table names and the foreign key links. Is this possible to do this automatically?

The database has security restrictions and it is not possible to create these diagrams directly so I attempted to copy the structure using data export. Unfortunately it seems to leave out the foreign key definitions and I can only create diagrams with unconnected tables.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/visual-db-tools/create-a-new-database-diagram-visual-database-tools?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [`Generate Scripts...`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/generate-scripts-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver16) wizard to get the DB structure, instead of `Export Data...`.

Once that wizard start, select objects  you want to include.

Then in `Set Scripting Options` page select `Advanced Options` and set `Types of data to script` to `Schema Only`, and any other setting you are interested (`Script Foreign Keys` is enabled by default).

Then you have a scritp to recreate objects in a blank db.

Comment: OP is asking about a database diagram, not a script?

Comment: He tell that he tried to export the structure, I think, to recreate db and generate the diagram from a copy of a database. But, I might have misunderstood him.

Comment: I do think the copying process could be the problem. The answer was good and I am trying it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create an entity relationship diagram (not an "entity resource" diagram). Management Studio can do this [see here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6269/sql-server-database-diagram-tool-in-management-studio/). Or try Visual DB ( https://visualdb.com ) it is automatic and displays just the table names and the foreign key links.